# Pasar una variable entre componentes | Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular5

tengo una aplicaciones que muestra unas categorías por ejemplo la url de 1 categoría seria así y el componentes seria CategoryComponent...

miweb.com/patienetes/

y quiero que cuando presionen un producto de la pagina de categoría mande el objeto del producto con toda la información al siguiente componente que seria ProductComponente con la URL la información no la quiero pasar or URL.

miweb.com/patienetes/patinete-extreme-5000

Espero haberme explicado bien, gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Si no he entendido mal lo que quieres es navegar de una página a otro y eso no es pasar datos entre componentes, a menos que los quieras pintar en una misma página, pero como cambiar la URl lo mejor es que te mires https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Yo tengo una pagina de categoría con todos los productos cuando hago click en 1 productos me lleva a la pagina del producto, pero quiero que aparte de que me lleve a la pagina del producto me mande el objeto del producto o la ID del producto pero que no se envié por parametros en la URL si no que se envie los datos ocultos, me has entendido ahora?

Comment: Esto tal vez te ayude:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821287/adding-parameter-to-angular-router-navigate

Comment: si quieres pasar de una página a otra para que se actualice la URL es usando un router, pero si quieres ocultar los parámetros me parece que eso no se puede. Existe maneras de hacerlo, pero no creo que sea las correctas por decirlo de alguna manera. Opciones guardar el id en el localStorage y recuperarlo en el metodo ngOnInit

Comment: Lo del localStorage lo había pensado pero si aceden directamente por URL no cargaría el producto ese es el problema que tengo si uso el localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que te tomado es establecer en la base de datos como clave primaria un valor que si que pueda pasar por URL por ejemplo el nombre del producto, en este casi el nombre del producto es Patinete Extreme 5000 pues la ID de este producto como clave primaria es patinete-extreme-5000 y esto es lo que paso por URL consiguiendo la URL que quería y con las categorías lo e echo igual.

miweb.com/patienetes/patinete-extreme-5000

Un saludo y gracias a todos por la ayuda.